# Como puedo realizar estos ejercicios? paso a paso

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Hola necesito ayuda urgente con este trabajo, no he podido realizar los ejercicios ya que no puedo desglosar las columnas como en el ejercicio 5

--1. Consulta de las secciones de un profesor en un semestre especifico.

```
SELECT Sec, profesor FROM [2019_1]
where Codigo= 'P991194'

Go
```

--2. Consulta de la cantidad de secciones por Campus ordenado por la cantidad de secciones en orden descuente

```
SELECT  count(Sec) Sec, Campus  FROM [2019_2]
group by Campus

GO
```

--3. Consulta de la cantidad de profesores por Campus por cantidad de profesores en orden ascendente.

```
SELECT  count(Codigo) Codigo, profesor, Campus  FROM [2020_1]
group by Campus, profesor
order by Profesor asc

Go
```

--4. Consulta de los Campus donde imparte un profesor en el semestre 2020-10

```
SELECT  campus, profesor  FROM [2020_1]
where Codigo= 'P991194'
group by campus, profesor
```

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora, y no he podido avanzar mas de ahi.

```
--8. Crear un procedimiento almacenado para obtener los cambios entre dos semestres (para saber cuáles secciones son nuevas, cerradas o suprimidas).
CREATE PROCEDURE SPcambios
    @semestre nvarchar(50),   
    @semestre nvarchar(50)   
as SELECT  *
    FROM [2019_1] a
    INNER JOIN [2019_2] b
        ON  a.NRC = b.NRC
    WHERE   ISNULL(a.Asignatura,'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Asignatura ,'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(a.Aulas, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Aulas, 'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(a.Campus, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Campus,'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(a.Clave, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Clave, 'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(a.Codigo, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Codigo, 'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(a.Dias, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Dias, -1)
        OR ISNULL(a.Horario, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Horario,'NULL')
        OR ISNULL(a.Profesor, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Profesor, 'NULL')


--11. Crear una función para determinar si una sección cambio de horario entre --un semestre y otro.

SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) FROM [2019_1], [2019_2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqq4r.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms1Ma.jpg
```

Comment: BetaM, deje las dos imagenes, una con los ejercicios requerido y otra con el formato y contenido del excel suministrado

Comment: En la descripcion he agregado lo que he podido hacer.
Cabe destacar que la data la tengo en una sola tabla, ahi es que no se cuantas tablas debo crear para resolver los ejercicios.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Importante revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Para esa estructura puedes utilizar la sentencia case.

```
DECLARE @Conjunto TABLE
                        (
                        Nrc        Int
                      , Clave      VarChar(100)
                      , Asignatura VarChar(100)
                      , Codigo     VarChar(100)
                      , Profesor   VarChar(100)
                      , Sec        Int
                      , Campus     VarChar(100)
                      , Tipo       VarChar(3)
                      , Horario    VarChar(100)
                      , Dias       Char(2)
                      , Aulas      VarChar(6)
                        );
INSERT INTO @Conjunto (Nrc, Clave, Asignatura, Codigo, Profesor, Sec, Campus, Tipo, Horario, Dias, Aulas)
VALUES
(40001,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','P991573','BLAS ACEVEDO',1,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '09 A 12', 'VI','FE303'),
(40008,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','P991536','CINTHIA PADI',2,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '17 A 18', 'JU','FE105'),
(40008,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','P991536','CINTHIA PADI',2,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '18 A 20', 'JU','FE103'),
(40012,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','P991582','ELISABETH TR',3,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '15 A 18', 'SA','CJA102'),
(40013,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','ADMINIS','*** SIN ASIG',4,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '19 A 22', 'MI','FE212'),
(40014,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','P960044','CARMEN HERRE',5,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '14 A 16', 'JU','FE210'),
(40014,'ADM-1120','PRINCIPIOS DE','P960044','CARMEN HERRE',5,'SANTO DOMINGO', 'TEO', '19 A 20', 'LU','FE003');

-- Solución
SELECT T.Nrc, T.Clave, T.Asignatura, T.Codigo, T.Profesor, T.Sec, T.Campus, T.TIPO,T.Aulas
, CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'LU' THEN T.Horario END AS LUNES
, CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'MA' THEN T.Horario END AS MARTES
, CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'MI' THEN T.Horario END AS MIERCOLES
, CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'JU' THEN T.Horario END AS JUEVES
, CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'VI' THEN T.Horario END AS VIERNES
, ISNULL(CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'SA' THEN T.Horario END,'') AS SABADO
, ISNULL(CASE WHEN T.Dias = 'DO' THEN T.Horario END,'') AS DOMINGO

FROM @Conjunto T
```

Como no tengo tu hoja de datos, he cargado una parte de la imagen, en una variable de tabla. El comportamiento es idéntico a tu tabla.

Si observas, con la sentencia Case, puedes evaluar una expresión y en caso de que sea correcta devuelves una columna. Esto lo puedes repetir tantas veces como quieras.

Si en la respuesta no quieres nulos, puedes envolver la expresión con la función is null, como te he puesto en el sábado y domingo.

[image: Solución]

[Case When SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: javi-fer2 gracias, me resulto, ya realce todos menos los ejercicios 8 y 11 quien me ayuda con esos ?

Comment: Pero ¿qué parte de los ejercicios 8 y 11 has intentado?

Comment: Listo ya agregue lo que intente hacer de los ejercicios 8 y 11

Comment: --9. Consular los profesores que imparten en más de cuatro campus.
Select  campus, codigo, Profesor from [2019_1]
where codigo IS NOT NULL 
group by campus, codigo, Profesor
having  count(Campus) > 4

Tambien en este tuve problemas, al igual que los de la descripcion . ejercicio 8, 9, 11

Comment: No has puesto la "data", entonces no es posible saber de donde sale [2019_1] y [2019_2]. Voy a suponer que realmente son dos lecturas de la misma tabla. Para qué son los parámetros. No veo en la pregunta nada que diga, que te dan parámetros. ¿Porqué ? ISNULL(columna,'NULL')<>ISNULL(COLUMNA,'NULL') Es una manera curiosa de comparar columnas (ojo esta parte debería de funcionar). Pero esto no     OR ISNULL(a.Dias, 'NULL') <> ISNULL(b.Dias, -1) Si a.dias es nulo y b.dias es nulo, siempre serán distintos. Aun cuando en tú idea no lo son.

Comment: Para obtener los cambios entre dos semestres (Si [2019_1] tiene un semestre y [2019_2] tiene otro semestre (que lo desconozco), lo que habrá que mirar es la columna Sec. Para saber cuales son nuevas. puedes utilizar un not in o not exists. Y desconozco que significa cerrada o suprimida. Si esto se contempla por una columna estado, o por la ausencia de horarios....

Comment: El ejercicio 11, si estás intentando realizar una comprobación, pero ¿donde se menciona la sección? Si lo que haces es crear una función escalar o table-inline con la idea de que tu desde una query externa realices lo que indicas, tendrás que hacerlo con un where en el conjunto y con un parámetro. (int sec)